# How to get values from the ArrayList for DetailView?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

i'm new to android development. i'm working on the app which using SAX parser for parsing XML file i'm getting the result and displaying them on the ListView but i'm unable to get value for detail view. Like i want when user click on particular row then that particular row display the DetailActivity.

i'm using this

> onItemClick()

In my code i'm getting the values from XML and save them in the ArrayList

> ArrayList title = new ArrayList();

able to display this title's in the ListView but how to show this same title in the DetailView also.

Here is my code below:-

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    static final String URL = "http://www.xyz.com/api.php?page_id=1";

    ItemList itemList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String XML = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);

        System.out.println("This XML is ========>"+XML);

       try
       {
           SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
           SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
           XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

           /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
           MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
           xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);

           ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(XML.getBytes());
           xr.parse(new InputSource(is));
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {

      }

      itemList = MyXMLHandler.itemList;

       ArrayList<String> listItem= itemList.getTitle();

    System.out.println("(ListItem)=======>"+listItem);


     ListView lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
     myAdapter adapter = new myAdapter(this, listItem);
     lview.setAdapter(adapter);


     lview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
     {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
         {


            // Starting new intent
             Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailClassJI.class);


             myAdapter ma = (myAdapter)parent.getAdapter();



         startActivity(in);
         }
    });
    }
}
```

ItemList.java

```
public class ItemList 
{
    ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();


    public ArrayList<String> getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title.add(title);
    }

}
```

XMLParser.java ( In which i had made HTTPRequest only)

```
public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }
}
```

XMLHandler.java

```
public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    public static ItemList itemList;
    public boolean current = false;
    public String currentValue = null;

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        current = true;

        if (localName.equals("posts"))
        {
            /** Start */ 
            itemList = new ItemList();

        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        current = false;

        if(localName.equals("title"))
        {
            itemList.setTitle(currentValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(current)
        {
            currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            current=false;
        }
    }
}
```

myAdapter.java

```
public class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    ArrayList<String> listTitle;


    Activity activity;

    public myAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> listTitle) {
        super();
        this.listTitle = listTitle;


        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listTitle.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView txtViewTitle;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder title;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(view==null)
        {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lview_row, null);
            title = new ViewHolder();

            title.txtViewTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);

            view.setTag(title);
        }
        else
        {
            title = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        title.txtViewTitle.setText(listTitle.get(position));


        return view;
    }
}
```

DetailClassJi.java

```
public class DetailClassJI extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail);

     // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();


     // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtItem);

    }
}
```

Can anyone please sugget me how i'll be able to show title also on detail view.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/UnTagged/feemaster/com/fee/master/ui/DetailView.java.htm

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Do below changes I hope It will work..

add below statement in getView(...)

```
title.txtViewTitle.setText(listTitle.get(position));
title.setTxtViewTitle(listTitle.get(position));
```

Change OnItemClickListener

```
lview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
     {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
         {


             ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();



            // Starting new intent
             Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailClassJI.class);
             in.putExtra("title", holder.getTxtViewTitle());
                startActivity(intent);

             myAdapter ma = (myAdapter)parent.getAdapter();



         startActivity(in);
         }
    });
```

add get Method in View holder

```
 class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView txtViewTitle;

               public String getTxtViewTitle(){
                   return txtViewTitle;
           }
           public void setTxtViewTitle(String txtViewTitle){
                   this.txtViewTitle = txtViewTitle;
           }

        }
```

finally get value in DetailsActivity like

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("title")
```

Comment: Thanks Bharkser for your quick reply but In ViewHolder Class complier giving me error and and showing in suggestions change getTxtViewTitle() to TextView or change TextView txtViewTitle to String txtViewTitle. What should i do in this mis-match condition.

Comment: use following statement in  getTxtViewTitle()  . return txtViewTitle.toString();